# Do a concatenation on javascript array value/key

Tags: javascript

Why concatenation on values or keys of a javascript array is not allowed?

```
var arr = {'date': year + ", " + month};
```

Or

```
var arr = {'to' + 'day': day};
```

Comment: This is an object, not array

Comment: What would you like to get? `var arr = {'date': year + ", " + month}` will be an object `arr` with property `date` (arr.date) and value `year + ", " + month`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, you're declaring an object not an array.

Secondly, your first example is possible:

```
var year = 2013,
    month = 7;
var obj = {'date': year + ', ' + month };
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
> {"date":"2013, 7"}
```

But to concatenate in a property you'll have to do it a bit differently:

```
var day = 'Monday',
    obj = {};
obj['to' + 'day'] = day;
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
> {"today":"Monday"}
```

Objects are a bit picky because the value to the left of the colon (`:`) is interpreted literally as a string (and not parsed like a value). That is to say that the following *would not* work:

```
var day = 'Monday',
    label = 'to' + 'day';
console.log(label);
> "today"
var obj = { label: day };
console.log(obj);
> {"label":"Monday"}
```

Note how `label` was interpreted as a string constant and not as a variable name.

Comment: @LeeTaylor: thanks; grammar, its an issue I'm faceing hear today. ;p

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
var asoc_arr = {};
asoc_arr['to'+'day'] = day;
```

Comment: This works, but calling it an associative array is a bit of a misnomer; you're creating an object, not an array.

Comment: +1 for key concatenation .

Answer (score 0):

Since you're creating a new object you might want to start with a JSON string, do all the required concatenation on it and then simply parse it into a JS object. Here is a simple example:

```
var year = "1990";
var month = "10";
var str = '{"date":"'+year+','+month+'"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj);

> { date: '1990,10' }
```

Comment: Why would you use JSON to create a Javascript object when you're already working in Javascript?

Comment: Just thought might be useful if there is a lot of concatenation before building an object, with strings(json string) it would feel more natural. Thanks for the down vote...